# Regex for finding link text and replacing it with filename

Tags: python, regex

I have a following link:
`<a href="domain.com/folder/subfolder/filename.html">domain.com/folder/subfolder/filename.html</a>`

I want to make it

- `<a href="http://www.domain.com/folder/subfolder/filename.html">filename</a>`
- `<a href="domain.com/folder/subfolder/filename.html">domain.com/folder/subfolder/filename</a>`

My regex for the first case is `<a\s*([^>]+)>[^<>]*?/?([^<>/.]+)\.?[^<>]*?</\s*a\s*>` and it's working by I doubt whether it is efficient and covers all cases.

As for the second, I didn't manage to make it working.

Note, that .html part can be absent or can be any extension, `http` also can be absent or be `https` or `ftp`.

UPD:
It should remove url params, like `?param1=val1&param2=val2`.

Comment: Google "html regex", click the first link, read the first answer.

Comment: @AlexHall why don't you just provide the link lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`(<a href="([^"?]*)[^"]*">)[^<]*(<\/a>)`](https://regex101.com/r/7p4hqO/2)

- `(<a href="([^"?]*)[^"]*">)` **Group 1**: A captured group containing the opening tag

  - `<a href="` Literal text
  - `([^"?]*)` **Group 2**: A captured group that contains any number of characters that are not `"` or `?`
  - `[^"]*` Any number of non `"` characters (this will match params, without capturing it in that group)
  - `">` Literal text
- `[^<]*` Any number of non `<` characters
- `(<\/a>)` **Group 3**: A captured group containing the closing tag

This should work for cases similar to the ones you showed in your post. If there are cases it doesn't work for, please add them to the post so we can use them to test.

So you run the regex, and replace with `(Group 1, opening tag) + (Group 2, file path from href) + (Group 3, closing tag)`.